# Why isn't the option list showing in HTML using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The select tag which is a child of the input text element simply does not display options that are added to the select element.

The HTML output and corresponding DOM are shown below:

[image]

Comment: An `<input>` can't have children. Question makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**input type="text"** cannot have children. You will have to place your **select** element outside.

Comment: input also has no end tag; there is no outside because there is no inside

Comment: That's a good constraint to have, I think I might adjust my editor to enforce no end tags on input elements.